# opendkim-testkey: [path]/dkim.key: open(): permission denied

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, postfix-mta, dkim

I installed postfix on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server and tested the default settings.  I was able to send a test email successfully.  Then I wanted to add dkim, which is where I started running into a problem.  My emails don't seem to be getting signed.

When I run

```
opendkim-testkey -d mydomain.com -s mail -vvv
```

I get

```
opendkim-testkey: /etc/postfix/dkim.key: open(): Permission denied
```

Ownership and permissions for /etc/postfix/dkim.key

```
-rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim   887 Sep  7 16:07 dkim.key
```

Postfix is also a part of the opendkim group

```
postfix : postfix opendkim
```

I hope someone has an idea, because I'm here scratching my head on this one.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was in /etc/opendkim.conf

I forgot to uncomment and edit some lines:

```
# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
Domain                  mydomain.com
KeyFile                 /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key
Selector                mail
```

These were originally all commented out.  I had previously purged and reinstalled opendkim and forgot this step.

Hopefully this will give someone else some help when they have a brain fart like me!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case only this helped me

```
chown -R opendkim:opendkim /etc/opendkim
chmod 0750 /etc/opendkim/keys
chmod 0600 /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private
```